# AWS DynamoDB DocumentClient not throwing expected error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB to store data and trying to read items using JavaScript. I have a function that will read an item from a specified table, but I want to detect when an item doesn't exist in the table:

```
function getChapterLocations() {
    var table = bibleSelect.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var chapter = bookSelect.value + " " + chapterSelect.value;
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key:{
            "chapter": chapter
        }
    };
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            currentLocations = {};
        } else {
            currentLocations = data.Item.locations;
        }
        getText();
    });
}
```

The problem is, even when an item doesn't exist in the table, `err` is always `null`. When an item doesn't exist, all I get is an error that looks something like this in the console:

> callListeners https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.164.0.min.js:48:1027
>   emit https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.164.0.min.js:48:695 emitEvent
>   https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.164.0.min.js:47:18756

I would just ignore this error, but when an item doesn't exist, it prevents `getText()` from being called.

Comment: Why should you receive an error if temp is not found.  Data is just going to be empty.    The GetItem operation returns a set of attributes for the item with the given primary key. If there is no matching item, GetItem does not return any data and there will be no Item element in the response.   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property

Comment: Ok, thank you, so my real problem is when I try to access locations from data.Item when there is no Item. I fixed it by checking if data.Item is not null instead of checking if there's an err is null.

Comment: Yep. You should also check of error is true and handle the error so the program is not going to crash